# VBA Wrong value from import xml file

Tags: xml, vba, import

From XML:

```
<PartNumberList>
<PartNumber PartNumber="DTRxxxxxxxxxxx" Cost="0" Description="Test" Manual="No" Mass="0.216" MountedOnHarness="Yes" PN_Source="WH" PN_Status="OK" PN_Type="Contact" PN_Version="1" Quantity="1" UnitType="Unit" />
</PartNumberList>
```

I want to pull it DTRxxxxxxxxxxx out into the spreadsheet but every time excel give me last atribute "unit"

This is my part of code from vba:

```
Set xmlNodeListPin = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//ConnectiveDevice[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromTag & "']/PinList/Pin[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromPinTag & "']/*/*/*/PartNumberList/PartNumber[@PartNumber]")
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each xmlNodePin In xmlNodeListPin
            'Debug.Print xmlNode.BaseName
            For Each myAtr In xmlNodePin.Attributes
            'If myAtr.BaseName = "Description" Then pnv = myAtr.Text
                'Debug.Print myAtr.BaseName & ": " & myAtr.Text
                Sheets("WL-test1").Cells(y, x).Value = myAtr.Text
            Next myAtr
            x = x + 1
            myCheck = 0
        Next xmlNodePin
        x = x + myCheck * (UBound(CableFrom) + 1)
        myCheck = 1
```

Any ideas?

Some code to generate the document

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set oDOC = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    oDOC.LoadXML "<PartNumberList>" & _
        "<PartNumber PartNumber='DTRxxxxxxxxxxx' Cost='0' Description='Test' Manual='No' Mass='0.216' MountedOnHarness='Yes' PN_Source='WH' PN_Status='OK' PN_Type='Contact' PN_Version='1' Quantity='1' UnitType='Unit' />" & _
        "</PartNumberList>"

    Debug.Assert oDOC.parseError.ErrorCode = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I want to help but the document is just a fragment, ConnectiveDevice does not appear in document

Comment: I want take only PartNumber="DTRxxxxxxxxxxx", how ?

Comment: Use `[@PartNumber='DTRxxxxxxxxxxx']` at the end of the XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    xmldoc.LoadXML "<ConnectiveDevice Tag='foo'><PinList><Pin Tag='bar'><a><b><c><PartNumberList>" & _
        "<PartNumber PartNumber='DTRxxxxxxxxxxx' Cost='0' Description='Test' Manual='No' Mass='0.216' MountedOnHarness='Yes' PN_Source='WH' PN_Status='OK' PN_Type='Contact' PN_Version='1' Quantity='1' UnitType='Unit' />" & _
        "</PartNumberList></c></b></a></Pin></PinList></ConnectiveDevice>"

    Debug.Assert xmldoc.parseError.ErrorCode = 0

    Dim ForDTRFromTag, ForDTRFromPinTag, y, x, myCheck, CableFrom
    ForDTRFromTag = "foo"
    ForDTRFromPinTag = "bar"

    Dim xmlNodeListPin As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    'Set xmlNodeListPin = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//ConnectiveDevice[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromTag & "']/PinList/Pin[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromPinTag & "']/*/*/*/PartNumberList/PartNumber[@PartNumber]")
    Set xmlNodeListPin = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//ConnectiveDevice[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromTag & "']/PinList/Pin[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromPinTag & "']/*/*/*/PartNumberList/PartNumber[@PartNumber]")


    If xmlNodeListPin.Length = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "bad xpath not no nodes found!"
        Stop
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim xmlNodePin As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
        For Each xmlNodePin In xmlNodeListPin
            'Debug.Print xmlNode.BaseName
            Dim myAtr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
            For Each myAtr In xmlNodePin.Attributes
                If myAtr.Name = "PartNumber" Then
                'If myAtr.BaseName = "Description" Then pnv = myAtr.Text
                    'Debug.Print myAtr.BaseName & ": " & myAtr.Text
                    'Sheets("WL-test1").Cells(y, x).Value = myAtr.Text

                    Debug.Print myAtr.NodeValue
                End If
            Next myAtr
            x = x + 1
            myCheck = 0
        Next xmlNodePin
        x = x + myCheck * (UBound(CableFrom) + 1)
        myCheck = 1
    End If

    '*****
    '*
    '*   OR with a single line ...
    '*
    '*****
    Dim xmlPartNumber As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Set xmlPartNumber = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//ConnectiveDevice[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromTag & "']/PinList/Pin[@Tag='" & ForDTRFromPinTag & "']/*/*/*/PartNumberList/PartNumber/@PartNumber")

    Debug.Print xmlPartNumber.nodeTypedValue


End Sub
```